# How to reindex fileds in kibana when using AWS Opensearch service

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, aws-elasticsearch, opensearch

I want to resolve conflicts in the kibana fields when we are using AWS elasticsearch / AWS Opensearch service.

We have 3 fields showing as conflicted in Kibana. How I can resolve that?

Comment: The solution is to reindex the data to a new index containing the correct mapping:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Ingest Pipelines` for this purpose. What you can do is to create a `pipeline` and then `reindex`.
E.g You want to rename `time` to `timestamp` in your index `myindex001`. You can do

```
    PUT _ingest/pipeline/my_pipeline
    {
      "description": "Rename 'time' to 'timestamp 'field from myindex001",
      "processors": [
        {
          "rename": {
            "field": "time",
            "target_field": "timestamp", 
            "ignore_missing": true
          } 
        }
      ]
    }
```

Now you can `reindex` your index.

```
    POST _reindex
    {
      "source": {
        "index": "myindex001"
      },
      "dest": {
        "index": "myindex001-back",
        "pipeline": "my_pipeline"
      }
    }
```

After this you can `reindex` your index to the original name by executing the above statement without `pipeline` part and names inverted.
You can also rename more than one field at a time by putting more than one `rename` in the pipeline.
Surely there will be a better way to do it.